# Return MYSQL QUERY INVERSED

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query in mysql, some one know how to return  an inverse query ?

```
mysql_query("
 SELECT * FROM batepapo 
 WHERE tipo='$t' && lang='$l' 
 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,100
");
```

The correct code now is

```
SELECT s.* FROM ( 
      SELECT t.* FROM batepapo
      t WHERE t.tipo='$t' AND t.lang='$l' 
      ORDER BY t.id DESC LIMIT 0,100) 
      AS s ORDER BY s.id")
```

Comment: What do you mean by inverse? The order of the results? What is returned?

Comment: What do you mean by inverse? The results that aren't in the first 100? Results from the equivalent table opapetab instead?

Comment: you mean ascending as oppose to descending?

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. 
I hope you have used [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because this looks terrifyingly insecure.

Comment: Eg: i have in the DB, Blue, red, gray, pink, Purple. i  want return the last 3 rowns, but inverse, now it returns me purple, pink, gray but i  want show gray, pink, purple

Comment: so change the order of how you're sorting the results. e.g. instead o `DESC`, use `ASC`.

Comment: But ASC will return me the 100 oldest results

Comment: Can't you just reverse your result set in your application? You can re-order an ordered result set but that's a little crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use your existing query as an inline view query, and the outer query can reorder the results.

As an example:

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM ( SELECT t.* 
           FROM batepapo t
          WHERE t.tipo='fooval' 
            AND t.lang='langval' 
          ORDER BY t.id DESC
          LIMIT 0,100
       ) s
 ORDER BY s.id
```

---

using union syntax:

```
( SELECT t.* 
    FROM batepapo t
   WHERE t.tipo='fooval' 
     AND t.lang='langval' 
   ORDER BY t.id DESC
   LIMIT 0,100
) ORDER BY id
```

---

I'm obligated to add some recommendations. 1) Consider that your existing code may be subject to SQL Injection vulnerabilities (i.e. we don't see any calls to the `mysql_real_escape_string` function.) and 2) The mysql_ interface is deprecated, and new code should use either PDO or mysqli interface.

Comment: You salved my life  thaks so much!!! it workeds fine to me i've change some thing i  will post the changes

Comment: there is a simpler way to write this.. use union syntax and you can avoid the additional query

Comment: @JohnRuddell: You've piqued my curiosity. Firstly, how would the use of the `UNION` set operator achieve the specified resultset (note that we aren't given any guarantee that the rows are unique, nor are we guaranteed that the id column is the first column in the SELECT list). But beyond that, how would one use `UNION` set operator  without using two `SELECT` keywords?

Comment: @spencer7593 I just posted an answer showing what I meant.. doesn't require more than one SELECT keyword or even the UNION keyword :)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query("
 SELECT * FROM batepapo 
 WHERE tipo='$t' && lang='$l' 
 ORDER BY id **ASC** LIMIT 0,100
");

Comment: All you have to do is remove `DESC` and it will default to `ASC`.

Comment: but i  wnat  show the lest 100 rowns but reverse the show method

Answer (score 0):

just to clarify what I was saying on spencer7593's answer.. you can also write the query like this.

using union syntax:

```
(SELECT t.* 
 FROM batepapo t
 WHERE t.tipo='fooval' 
    AND t.lang='langval' 
 ORDER BY t.id DESC
 LIMIT 0,100) 
 ORDER BY id
```

basically you just do the select and then order afterwards. this seems like it wouldn't work and it isn't documented in MySQL, but its obvious from the [grammar](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L7322):